# How to Use Mouse Lock in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome

I'm working on creating a FPS-type game for the browser using WebGL/Javascript and have been unable to successfully implement the very recently added "Mouse Lock" feature to Chrome and Firefox.

I have tried the example code from all three of these sources to no avail:
http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=72754

http://blog.sethladd.com/2011/09/mouse-lock-for-html5-fps-games.html

http://jsfiddle.net/jdias/3dqBL/

So, that leads me to my question. What is the correct way to lock the mouse in the latest versions of Chrome and Firefox (Minefield)? I would really love to get this working!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've tried the example code at all the aforementioned links. Also, interestingly, even the Mouse Lock example in one of Google's presentations (only three weeks ago) doesn't work for me:

http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/html5-therealbleedingedge/demos/mouselock.html

This is a shot in the dark, but could it be due to the fact that I'm on Linux and the browsers may be a little behind in the newest features?

Comment: Just tried the above Google Mouse Lock demo on Windows with the latest Chrome and Firefox Nightly. Same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mouselock actually hasn't been implemented in Firefox, but there is an experimental build located at: http://people.mozilla.com/~tmielczarek/mouselock+gamepad/ . With google Chrome, get the latest version and go into about:flags and check --enable-pointer-lock. 
I hope that helps.

Comment: @Pat Briggs Hmm, it looks like you need to wait a little bit, as support in chrome canary landed only 2 days ago: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=72754#c69